# Package reledmac Error: edtext without Xfootnote

Tags: reledmac, missing, xfootnote

Can someone point me at the reason for this?

```
See the reledmac package documentation for explanation.
```

The reledmac documentation mentions `\Xfootnote` but doesn't say what it is, where I get it, or what it can do (nor why I can't use `\edtext` without it).

Mnon-WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
stuff \edtext{in}{on} my notes
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

I have obviously misunderstood something, but I can't see what.

Comment: Could the `X` be a place holder? The documentation also mentions `\Afootnote` and `\Bfootnote`. Indeed the example in §13.3 has `\Afootnote` in it: `stuff \edtext{in}{\Afootnote{on}} my notes` seems to work.

Comment: thats is @moewe. I will answer.

Comment: That never dawned on me (not enough covfefe). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xfootnote` mean... \Afootnote, or \Bfootnote of \Cfootnote etc.

By default, there five level of footnote with reledmac (that is explained in § 6.2 of the handbook).

to associate a footnote to a lemma, reledmac need to determine which level of footnote is concerned.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
stuff \edtext{in}{\Afootnote{footnote on level A}\Bfootnote{footnote B}} my notes
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

You can create your own command to call directly one predefined level.

```
\newcommand{\mynote}[2]{%
  #1%
}{\Bfootnote{#1}}
```

And then do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
stuff \mynote{in}{on} my notes
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to learn how to prespecify that \edtext must always use level B — but at least I have had my caffeine now.

Comment: cf my complement. But please, validate answer.

Comment: I already did...

Comment: no, you vote up, no validate. To validate an answer on the "checkmark". Cf https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/375021

Comment: Sorry, finger slippage.